# Yii: The URL pattern for route is not a valid regular expression

Tags: php, regex, yii

I've got a very strange problem. I have some simple routes configured which worked on my local server (PHP 5.3 and 5.4, both work fine) but on the deployment server (PHP 5.3.23) they failed, so I even switched to the default routes preconfigured by Yii (even though I'm pretty sure mine was correct), but they also fail with the following exception `The URL pattern "<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>" for route "<controller>/view" is not a valid regular expression.`

Here are the routes:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        //'^$' => 'site/index',
        //'<view:[\w\-\_\d]+>' => 'site/paged',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    'showScriptName' => true,
),
```

as you can see I've commented out my two routes to make sure I didn't made some stupid mistake.

What is wrong?

---

here's the backtrace if anyone's interested https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltles.png

Comment: Start working backwards by examining the value of `$this->pattern` at the point where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Try to escape the forward slashes `\/`

Comment: just give a try by commenting out the rules part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After short investigation, this is what I've found.

```
preg_match() Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0
```

It seems that the problem is that my config file is UTF-8. The solution is to update PHP & PCRE.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that yii complains on the part with `<controller>/view`. For url rules you can use special placeholders with `_` prefix, for module, controller, action - respectively `_m`, `_c`, `_a`. In your case you could use something like that:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        //'^$' => 'site/index',
        //'<view:[\w\-\_\d]+>' => 'site/paged',
        '<_c>/<id:\d+>'=>'<_c>/view',
        '<_c>/<_a>/<id:\d+>'=>'<_c>/<_a>',
        '<_c>/<_a>'=>'<_c>/<_a>',
    ),
    'showScriptName' => true,
),
```